# Linkify address working on only one half of the address

Tags: android, linkify

The below code shows how I am getting the address from a sample JSON file:

```
String address = "";
if(jObjIndex2.has("address")) {
     JSONArray jsonAddress = jObjIndex2.getJSONArray("address");
     JSONObject jsonAddressObj = jsonAddress.getJSONObject(0);
     address = address + String.valueOf(jsonAddressObj.getString("line1"));
     if (jsonAddressObj.has("line2")) {
         address = address + ", " + jsonAddressObj.getString("line2");
         if (jsonAddressObj.has("line3"))
              address = address + ", " + jsonAddressObj.getString("line3");
         }
         address = address + ", "+ jsonAddressObj.getString("city");
         address = address + ", "+ jsonAddressObj.getString("state");
         address = address + ", "+ jsonAddressObj.getString("zip");
     }
```

The output of this will look something like this:
**The White House, 
1600 Pennsylvania Avenue NW, 
Washington, DC, 20500**

Here "The White house" is from line1 and "1600 Pennsylvania Avenue NW" is from line2.

After Linkify, am getting only line2 linkified with the state city and zip, not the line1. 
If an address has only line1, then the address is not getting linkified at all.

My linkify code is:
Linkify.addLinks((TextView) findViewById(R.id.candidateAddress), Linkify.MAP_ADDRESSES);

If anyone knows why its acting like that, could you please comment.